# NTSC -> ADC -> USB. A video digitzer circuit

Tags: usb, adc, vga, ntsc

I'm working on a project that ultimately needs to incorporate an analog video camera input, digitizing it and spitting it out a USB port as an MPEG stream.  My general aim is for roughly a VGA resolution, so it's not super demanding in those terms.

While I've been digging quite a lot, I'm having a tough time finding ICs or example circuits that aren't either overkill or more focused on frame grabs rather than real-time streams.

Overkill examples are the enormous line of TI products that are aimed at home A/V receivers with multiple HDMI IO, for example.

I want this to essentially be a stand-alone module, but the larger project has a microcontroller and other elements that make me lean away from any SOC or FPGA or Linux-on-OMAP etc solutions, in favor of what I hope and would think could be a simpler circuit.

Can anyone here point me in the right direction?  Or give me an appropriate kick-in-the-head, if I'm running off half-cocked in my thinking so far?

BTW - there is one cool, albeit dated design that I found here
Homebrew digitizer:  http://www.techmind.org/vd/vidmk2.html

Comment: Since I'm not really getting any feedback on this question - I'll update where things are and see if anyone can help me out...

Comment: I'm going to try the TI ADS825e which is a CMOS ADC that spits out parallel 10bit signal at 40MHz.  I'll use a TI SN74HC166AIDRQ1 PISO shift register to serialize my data stream, and will push that into a microcontroller (which I've not yet identified exactly.)  I'm hoping I can push the serial input through the micro and out the USB of the microcontroller.

Comment: I'd still love feedback though, if anyone here has any for me ;-)  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It turns out that doing stable NTSC recovery is a bit tricky; also decoding the phase-modulated color data will be non-trivial.  Usually this is done in an ASIC, with or without the MPEG.  I believe NTSC to USB (at least the version without the MPEG) is available off the shelf, connectorized, for about $40.  Which really raises the question - do you want to get buried in a DIY effort for this particular sub-project, or do you want to solve the overall problem of which this is a part?

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's really helpful. I want to keep my cost of the overall final project down - but perhaps you're right about that being easiest.  Can you recommend specific modules like you describe?

Comment: No, only that if you are using linux or osx instead of windows you research any given USB video capture device carefully before buying to be sure it is supported.

Comment: If you want to do it for the learning experience, you might learn a whole lot if you go the GnuRadio approach - the 10bit at 40MHz is enough to stick into USB 2.0 High Speed, with a microcontroller that can support it, you can get the PC to deal with stable NTSC recovery, phase demodulation etc.. a good winter project to learn about software defined radio :)

Comment: We are inviting experts for specialized questions like this. Now there is a new proposal at Areas 51: [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies?referrer=lxeiaDBzsJIqpGpL-P5bMg2) which focuses on Television and Broadcast in depth. Please join and invite others.

Comment: I've found that this is MUCH easier to do with a nice lightweight kernel running on an ARM with an NTSC decoder like the TI TVP5146.  Thanks all for the great suggestions on this over the past few months.

Comment: There is a whole bunch of products at Conexant, including Polaris, which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gregory. I'm not sure if you saw the last comment in the thread dated May 31 2012, but I opted to go with an ARM processor with a TI TVP5146.

Comment: I did not bother with reading all comments. I just hope it worked for you :) But if you need same application next time, check out Conexant. It's funny,  used it in 2009, but did not know about this community.

Comment: No worries Gregory. This is all up here in case somebody else needs the info, so maybe they can investigate the Conexant products. Anything particular you'd recommend?